# Required a field in a function

Tags: c#

I use this entity for my REST API in C#:

```
namespace WebRestApi.Entity
{
     public class Sensors
     {
         public int? SensorID { get; set; }
         public int? LocationIDRef { get; set; }
         public int? SensorType { get; set; }
         public int? Mode { get; set; }
         public string SensorName { get; set; }
         public int? HUBID { get; set; }

         public string? NotMergedData { get; set; }
     }
}
```

I want to use it in this controller:

```
[Route("assing-to-location")]
[HttpPost]
public ResponseApi setLocationForSensor(Sensors sensors)
```

Now, how can I say that `LocationIDRef` is only required, others are not required?

That is, it is mandatory to say it only here in this `setLocationForSensor`.

Comment: If they should behave differently in different occassions then they should be different classes.

Comment: You could use the [`Required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) data annotation, or alternatively [fluent validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html).

Comment: You should avoid working with actual entities for similar cases. You should create a separate ViewModel and pass it as an argument, then you can check this model as per the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IValidatableObject` like

```
namespace WebRestApi.Entity
{
     public class Sensors : IValidatableObject
     {
         public int? SensorID { get; set; }
         public int? LocationIDRef { get; set; }
         public int? SensorType { get; set; }
         public int? Mode { get; set; }
         public string SensorName { get; set; }
         public int? HUBID { get; set; }

         public string? NotMergedData { get; set; }
         
         public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
         {
             if (LocationIDRef == null)
                yield return new ValidationResult($"The {nameof(LocationIDRef)} Is not valid.", new[] { nameof(LocationIDRef) });
         }
     }

}
```

Then in the controller:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

will make it return 400 with the problematic property.